From Wightman to HK axioms for "non-neutral (charged?)" fields
Wightman axioms deal with operator-valued distributions (Wightman fields) whose values are unbounded operators in general.
On the other hand, the Haag-Kastler axioms deal with net of observables, where each observable's values are bounded operators.
According to papers like H.J. BORCHERS and JAKOB YNGVASON or John T. Cannon & Arthur M. Jaffe, the standard way to pass from Wightman to HK is unbounded functional calculus with the exponential function.
That is, if $\phi$ is a Wightman field whose values are (unbounded) self-adjoint operators, we consider $e^{i \phi}$ for construction of observables.
However, this can only apply for "neutral (or Hermitian)" fields. On the other hand, there are many particles which do NOT coincide with the antiparticles, so that the corresponding Wightman field cannot be self-adjoint operators.
I wonder how we should extend to such cases. The most intuitive way would be to deal with the particle and antiparticle "separately", but I do not see clearly how to actually do so.
Could anyone clarify for me?

You can decompose a complex scalar field as $\phi = \phi_{real} + i \phi_{imag}$, and then apply the same tricks to the real and imaginary components.
The general idea here is to consider all the bounded functions of $\phi$ as observables.  Don't get hung up on the exponential.  It's just a convenience for scalars.

Thank you. So, we need two distinct nets of observables?

Also, why is the exponential convenient for scalar (only)?
